# Cannot run Git pull on PowerShell in TFS Build Pipeline

Tags: git, powershell, tfs, build, continuous-integration

In my current pipeline I need to git pull other repository than the current one, but when I try to execute the git pull (either with powershell or cmd) it just gets blocked and never moves on.

If I try the commands where the agent is running they are executed correctly.

This is my powershell script:

```
Write-Host (Get-Location)

Set-Location -Path xxx

Write-Host (Get-Location)

#Update the repository, with no prints

Write-Host "Updating"
Invoke-Expression "& git pull origin develop --verbose" 

Write-Host "Updated"

exit 0
```

When I run this, I get the "Updating" but then it just blocks there and nothing happens.

Can anyone point me the right direction to do this?

Comment: Not sure, but my gut feeling is with the handshake to gitserver... Have you tried git pull on the agent?
Here is my local server logs, if may help ...
```/Users/demokritos/work/src/github.com/anotherfolder/projectK/weirdfolder    
     /Users/demokritos/work/src/github.com/abc     
     Updating     
     Looking up github.com ... done.
     Connecting to github.com (port 9418) ... 192.60.253.113 done.
     From git://github.com/abc/xyz
    * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
    = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
    Already up-to-date.
    Updated
```

Comment: Did you just want to pull the other remote to your `Build.SourcesDirectory` such as `c:\agent\_work\1\s` in your build agent?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT no, I have it in other folder location, that's why i "Set-Location" to another path

Comment: @JorgeLima If so, suggest you also give a try with default `Build.SourcesDirectory` to see whether the error related to this or not. If you could pull successfully when you are using the `Build.SourcesDirectory`, please check if your build services account have enough permission such as write on the other path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this helps someone, I was able to overcome this issue by using the following:

```
Invoke-Expression "& git -c http.extraheader='AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)' pull --progress origin develop -q"
```

It seems that the request was blocked asking for credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, having lots of PS1 scripts around to build Delphi projects on TFS 2017. As long as we have been using agents of version 1.105.7, everything was fine. When updating to the new agents (2.120.2), scripts were not able to fetch changes anymore and just blocked the build pipeline.

After doing heavy research, I found one difference between the two agent version:

- old agents (1.105.7) used the system configs for the git **credential.manager** attribute, which was set to "**manager**"
- new agents (2.120.2) somehow cleared this setting, meaning, no credentials were in place and the script "prompted" for username/password and thus blocked

To come across this issue, I just had to set the credential helper again on the build machine.

```
\path\to\tfs\agent\externals\git\cmd\git.exe config --system credential.helper manager
```

Answer (score 0):

You could directly use the git command through command line task such as below:
[image]

First make sure you could manually run git command successfully on the agent with your **build services account**. If the other repository need some authentication,  the script or command should also include the authentication.

Also try to enable your build definition to run `Git.exe`.
On the variables tab set this variable:

```
system.prefergit    true
```

More details please refer this tutorial: [Run Git commands in a script](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/scripts/git-commands)

If you still get the error, suggest you to enable more verbose logging  for trouble shooting. To do this please follow:  enable TFS Build debug logging by adding a variable named *system.debug* and setting its value to '**true**'.

Comment: Hey, I tried this but unfortunately i couldn't manage to make it work :\ I also followed the documentation with no success either.

Comment: @JorgeLima What's detail error you got? Could you share related build log?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this issue and you are trying to use the System.AccessToken in a Release instead of a Build you need to Allow Scripts to use OAuth in the environments “Agent phase” settings (advanced)

This setting also exists for Builds